# Create Personal VPN connection using NEVPNManager

Tags: ios, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I am trying to create VPN connection in my app. I go through this link 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager 
but did not find any official code to use NEVPNManager and even not found any tutorial to use this NEVPNManager.

I am new to VPN concept and don't know that much about it. so Can anyone give some solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial help me to create VPN connection.

http://blog.moatazthenervous.com/create-a-vpn-connection-with-apple-swift/

VPN file for connection and disconnection

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

  // MARK: - NEVPNManager
    // MARK: -


    private var vpnLoadHandler: (Error?) -> Void { return
    { (error:Error?) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Could not load VPN Configurations")
            self.removeToast()
            return;
        }

        self.showToast(msg: STRINGVALUES.kCreatingConnection)


        //VPN connection via Username password
        let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
        let kcs = KeychainService()
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.sharedSecret

        //For the security purpose added word xyz in password .so it should be remove while connecting


        if self.selectedSever != nil{
            self.selectedSever?.password = (self.selectedSever?.password.replacingOccurrences(of: "xyz", with: ""))!
            p.username = self.selectedSever?.userName
            p.serverAddress = self.selectedSever?.serverAddress
            kcs.save(key: "SHARED", value: (self.selectedSever?.password)!)

            kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: (self.selectedSever?.password)!)
            p.sharedSecretReference = kcs.load(key: STRINGVALUES.kShared)
            p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: STRINGVALUES.kVPN_Pswd)
            p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
            p.disconnectOnSleep = false

            // Check for free subscriber
            if self.selectedSever?.serverType == STRINGVALUES.VIP.lowercased() && !Singleton.checkForPaidReciept(){

                self.disconnectVPN()
                Helper.showAlert(sender: self, title: STRINGVALUES.AppName, message: AlertMessage.kValidateSubscription)
                return

            }


            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = p
            self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = STRINGVALUES.AppName
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true

            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnSaveHandler)
        }else{

        }


        }

    }


    private var vpnSaveHandler: (Error?) -> Void { return
    { (error:Error?) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Could not save VPN Configurations")
            self.removeToast()
            return
        } else {
            do {
                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
            } catch let error {
                print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
                self.removeToast()
            }
        }
        }
        //self.vpnlock = false
    }



    public func connectVPN() {
        //For no known reason the process of saving/loading the VPN configurations fails.On the 2nd time it works
        do {
            try self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnLoadHandler)

        } catch let error {
            print("Could not start VPN Connection: \(error.localizedDescription)" )
            self.removeToast()
        }
    }

    public func disconnectVPN() ->Void {
        vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()


    }

    func vpnConnectionStatusChanged(){

       let status = self.vpnManager.connection.status
        print("VPN connection status = \(status)")

        switch status {
        case NEVPNStatus.connected:

            showToast(msg: STRINGVALUES.kConnected)




        case NEVPNStatus.invalid, NEVPNStatus.disconnected :

            showToast(msg: STRINGVALUES.kDisconnected)


        case NEVPNStatus.connecting , NEVPNStatus.reasserting:

            showToast(msg: STRINGVALUES.kConnecting)


        case NEVPNStatus.disconnecting:
            showToast(msg: STRINGVALUES.kDisconnecting)

        default:
            print("Unknown VPN connection status")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Shipra, Can you please share snippet here? Actually i am getting error `Error starting VPN Connection The operation couldn’t be completed. (NEVPNErrorDomain error 1.)`

Comment: @AnuragSharma, I have updated the my answer with some code

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I am using IKEv2 configuration and the shared key is not required in that. So, I used EAP for authentication and it worked. I think you don't need to make `p.useExtendedAuthentication = true` Because you are not using EAP.

Comment: Hi @AnuragSharma can you please provide me reference for vpn. Actually I want to trigger VPN connection programmatically using Swift4

Comment: @Ashish, Please check my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992921/4933696) and for the API reference you can always read Personal VPN Apple API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/personal_vpn),

Make sure you are clear about "How the user and server authentication will work in your VPN connection".

By using the code in my answer you can surely trigger the VPN connection if you have CONFIGURED IT CORRECTLY.

Moreover, you can use the "Apple Configurator 2" Mac OS application to check your VPN profile's configuration is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragSharma will go through your reference.

Comment: @AnuragSharma I've implemented your solution, but it configure another - safe VPN, instead of invoking my existing corporate vpn, i.e Per-App-VPN.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a IKEv2 configuration of VPN using Network Extension (Without shared key and certificate) in Swift 4.2:

```
final class VPNHandler {

    let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()

    func initVPNTunnelProviderManager() {

        print("CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES...")
        self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error) -> Void in

            if((error) != nil) {

                print("VPN Preferences error: 1")
            } else {

                let IKEv2Protocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()

                IKEv2Protocol.username = vpnUser.username
                IKEv2Protocol.serverAddress = vpnServer.serverID //server tunneling Address
                IKEv2Protocol.remoteIdentifier = vpnServer.remoteID //Remote id
                IKEv2Protocol.localIdentifier = vpnUser.localID //Local id

                IKEv2Protocol.deadPeerDetectionRate = .low
                IKEv2Protocol.authenticationMethod = .none
                IKEv2Protocol.useExtendedAuthentication = true //if you are using sharedSecret method then make it false
                IKEv2Protocol.disconnectOnSleep = false

                //Set IKE SA (Security Association) Params...
                IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256
                IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
                IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14
                IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1440
                //IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.isProxy() = false

                //Set CHILD SA (Security Association) Params...
                IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256
                IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
                IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14
                IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1440

                let kcs = KeychainService()
                //Save password in keychain...
                kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: vpnUser.password)
                //Load password from keychain...
                IKEv2Protocol.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "VPN_PASSWORD")

                self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = IKEv2Protocol
                self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "Safe Login Configuration"
                self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true

                self.vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
                //print(IKEv2Protocol)

                //Set rules
                var rules = [NEOnDemandRule]()
                let rule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
                rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
                rules.append(rule)

                print("SAVE TO PREFERENCES...")
                //SAVE TO PREFERENCES...
                self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                    if((error) != nil) {

                        print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                    } else {

                        print("CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES AGAIN...")
                        //CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES AGAIN...
                        self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                            if ((error) != nil) {
                                print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                            } else {
                                var startError: NSError?
                                do {
                                    //START THE CONNECTION...
                                    try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                                } catch let error as NSError {

                                    startError = error
                                    print(startError.debugDescription)
                                } catch {

                                    print("Fatal Error")
                                    fatalError()
                                }
                                if ((startError) != nil) {
                                    print("VPN Preferences error: 3")

                                    //Show alert here
                                    print("title: Oops.., message: Something went wrong while connecting to the VPN. Please try again.")

                                    print(startError.debugDescription)
                                } else {
                                    //self.VPNStatusDidChange(nil)
                                    print("Starting VPN...")
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        } //END OF .loadFromPreferences //

    }

    //MARK:- Connect VPN
    static func connectVPN() {
        VPNHandler().initVPNTunnelProviderManager()
    }

    //MARK:- Disconnect VPN
    static func disconnectVPN() {
        VPNHandler().vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
    }

    //MARK:- check connection staatus
    static func checkStatus() {

        let status = VPNHandler().vpnManager.connection.status
        print("VPN connection status = \(status.rawValue)")

        switch status {
        case NEVPNStatus.connected:

            print("Connected")

        case NEVPNStatus.invalid, NEVPNStatus.disconnected :

            print("Disconnected")

        case NEVPNStatus.connecting , NEVPNStatus.reasserting:

            print("Connecting")

        case NEVPNStatus.disconnecting:

            print("Disconnecting")

        default:
            print("Unknown VPN connection status")
        }
    }
}
```

Code for keychain:

```
//MARK:- Variables for keychain access

// Identifiers
let serviceIdentifier = "MySerivice"
let userAccount = "authenticatedUser"
let accessGroup = "MySerivice"

// Arguments for the keychain queries
var kSecAttrAccessGroupSwift = NSString(format: kSecClass)

let kSecClassValue = kSecClass as CFString
let kSecAttrAccountValue = kSecAttrAccount as CFString
let kSecValueDataValue = kSecValueData as CFString
let kSecClassGenericPasswordValue = kSecClassGenericPassword as CFString
let kSecAttrServiceValue = kSecAttrService as CFString
let kSecMatchLimitValue = kSecMatchLimit as CFString
let kSecReturnDataValue = kSecReturnData as CFString
let kSecMatchLimitOneValue = kSecMatchLimitOne as CFString
let kSecAttrGenericValue = kSecAttrGeneric as CFString
let kSecAttrAccessibleValue = kSecAttrAccessible as CFString


class KeychainService: NSObject {

    func save(key:String, value:String) {

        let keyData: Data = key.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: false)!
        let valueData: Data = value.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: false)!

        let keychainQuery = NSMutableDictionary();

        keychainQuery[kSecClassValue as! NSCopying] = kSecClassGenericPasswordValue
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrGenericValue as! NSCopying] = keyData
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrAccountValue as! NSCopying] = keyData
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrServiceValue as! NSCopying] = "VPN"
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrAccessibleValue as! NSCopying] = kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly
        keychainQuery[kSecValueData as! NSCopying] = valueData;

        // Delete any existing items
        SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionary)

        SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
    }

    func load(key: String)->Data {

        let keyData: Data = key.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: false)!

        let keychainQuery = NSMutableDictionary();

        keychainQuery[kSecClassValue as! NSCopying] = kSecClassGenericPasswordValue
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrGenericValue as! NSCopying] = keyData
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrAccountValue as! NSCopying] = keyData
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrServiceValue as! NSCopying] = "VPN"
        keychainQuery[kSecAttrAccessibleValue as! NSCopying] = kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly
        keychainQuery[kSecMatchLimit] = kSecMatchLimitOne
        keychainQuery[kSecReturnPersistentRef] = kCFBooleanTrue

        var result: AnyObject?

        let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) { SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, UnsafeMutablePointer($0)) }

        if status == errSecSuccess {

            if let data = result as! NSData? {

                if let value = NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    //print(value)
                }
                return data as Data;
            }
        }
        return "".data(using: .utf8)!;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the vpnUser and vpnServer objects are, exactly?

Comment: Yes, The `vpnUser` and `vpnServer` are the structs actually and they contain contants 'Strings'.

Comment: Hi @AnuragSharma , I don't have any VPN server, is it possible to use device local IP or local host as VPN server to make a proxy VPN ? Even if I get some free VPN servers to use, from where do I get the username , localIdentifier and RemoteIdentifier ? If possible could you please answer my this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365588/ios-network-extension-local-vpn