# Block URLs using NetworkExtension

Tags: ios, aws-lambda

I'm trying to add some content filtering into my iOS app. Namely, I'd like if it could block certain URLs. I've poked around with some VPN stuff, but I'm getting lost. My basic understanding is that I need to create a Personal VPN using `NetworkExtension` and then I'll still need a server to point to where the content filtering will actually happen.

Other than that I've seen some mention of using a custom VPN to do the filtering on the client side (on the iPhone / iPad). I've ruled out using a content filter, as that only works for monitored devices.

What I'm trying to get more info on is:

- How do I create a personal or custom VPN?
- How do I spin up a server to filter this content? Could I use aws lambda?

I've read through all of these:

- https://kean.blog/post/vpn-configuration-manager
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992921/3320342
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/96777
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74464?answerId=218089022#218089022

But I'm still stumped. Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what your app does, and how you define "content filtering"? Does your app include a web browser?