# iOS Network Extension : Local VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, networkextension

I am trying to create a VPN, but without any VPN server. I am not sure if this is possible or not, but I Have seen apps which creates VPN and their VPN configuration ther server address is 127.0.0.1

I am using `NEVPNProtocolIPSec`

```
        let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()            
        p.username = "ScreenCoach"
        p.serverAddress = "MY_DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS"
        
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.sharedSecret
        
        let kcs = KeychainService();
        kcs.save(key: "SHARED", value: "AppDemoKey")
        kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: "rootuser")
        p.sharedSecretReference = kcs.load(key: "SHARED")
        p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "VPN_PASSWORD")
        p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
        p.disconnectOnSleep = false
```

In the `serverAddress` I have tried 127.0.0.1 , 0.0.0.0 and also my device's IP Address but nothing seems to work, and I am getting error alert message : `The VPN server did not respond.`

I don't know much about networking stuff, so can anyone please guide me here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

`My Goal :` Use custom DNS server for all the DNS queries throughout the device, without using an actual VPN server, so just a proxy VPN with DNS settings. Also I can not use NEDNSSettingsManager because iOS 12 is our minimum target.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this serverless VPN?

Comment: @JamesZ actually I want my device to use a custom DNS server, which I am adding in On Demand Rules. I can't use NEDNSProxyProvider as this appraoch is for supervised devices, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @superGokuN: It is possible to use Packet Tunnel provider [with empty match domains which should give you all DNS traffic](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/35027?answerId=395911022#395911022) and you can only add your DNS server in include routes which will eliminate any traffic not going to your DNS server from being received by your NE.